# How to create an interactive number line in .Net/HTML5

Tags: c#, .net, html

I'm attempting to create an interactive [number line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line) to aid in basic addition/subtraction learning for math students using HTML5 and .NET.  I'm trying to figure out how to create an interactive number line, one which the user can drag a marker(s) on the line to different numbers and see the addition/subtraction result.

From what I've researched so far, the [slider bar](http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/) in HTML5 may be the solution, but I'm not sure if it can handle ranges.

Any starting points from the gurus out there?

Comment: Can you please ask a specific question? I don't know what you're asking for.

Comment: @Gabe Sure. I'm trying to figure out how to create an interactive number line, one which the user can drag a marker(s) on the line to different numbers and see the addition/subtraction result.

Comment: @Gabe This question is more than specific enough, two users didn't have any issue there. You and casperOne definitely jumped the gun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to include .net in this.  HTML5 can handle this use-case completely client-side in javascript.  I was in the middle of crafting one using the Canvas API but then I tripped across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182494/how-to-draw-number-lines-using-html) which basically gives you what you need to know to make the number lines, you only need to grab the click events and create a spot to display the addition result.  That should be pretty easy unless you are a serious beginner with Canvas, if you are then let me know your specific issue and I'll see if I can expand this post.

With relation to sblom's answer, JQuery would work beautifully on this too.  But I would not involve .net technologies unless you really need some sort of server-side processing technology, which you don't here.

Comment: ah this is great, thank you. Surprised that question didn't come up on the search. I'm a beginner with Canvas, but i'll try this out first before I ask for more help, my question was mainly to figure out what would work best for this case.

Answer (score 1):

There are many HTML UI toolkits out there that provide a Range Slider, which I think will do almost exactly what you want.

You should check out JQuery UI's range slider to get you started: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range