# Drawing Math number lines in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to draw the number line(as it is in below link) dynamically in html.

http://www.mathsisfun.com/number-line.html

Can you please point to some javascript library to achieve the same?

Comment: Does it have to look exactly like that example? You could represent the same idea using side by side boxes with the numbers inside, which is easy to represent in HTML.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182494/how-to-draw-number-lines-using-html

Comment: That can be done purely in HTML and CSS, there is no need for script and certainly no need for a library.

Comment: @RobG Thanks. Can you please help with some examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple CSS example. Note that I am pretty rubbish at CSS, this will probably only work in Firefox, Safari, *et al* and look like crap in IE.

If you are going to do lots of these of different sizes, a script to generate the markup might be handy, but it should generate HTML that is served to the client, not done using script at the client.

```css
.lineContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
  width: 21px;
  Height: 8px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lineRightEnd {
  border-right: 0;
}

.numberContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.number {
  width: 22px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.numberLeftEnd {
  width: 10px;
  Height: 5px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>A number line</p>
<div class="lineContainer">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="line lineRightEnd"></div>
  <div class="numberContainer">
    <div class="numberLeftEnd"></div>
    <div class="number">-5</div>
    <div class="number">-4</div>
    <div class="number">-3</div>
    <div class="number">-2</div>
    <div class="number">-1</div>
    <div class="number">0</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
    <div class="number">3</div>
    <div class="number">4</div>
    <div class="number">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobG.. I can improvise on the above mentioned example..